# How can I find my questions that have no accepted answer yet?

Tags: support, answers, search

I tend to forget to accept my own answer after the two days of waiting time. How do I find all my questions that have no accepted answer yet?

Comment: Did you check your [profile's question section](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1184842/jan?tab=questions) ?

Comment: @Kedarnath There is a list of all my questions, i.e. I don't know how to filter for questions without accepted answers. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: See [What do the colors on Stack Overflow mean?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean), jan.

Comment: Can't you find the [different](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ebt7.png) ? the blue one is accepted one and red is non accepted one. Watch then properly.

Comment: Also see [How do I search?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use advanced search for this.

Try searching with:

> [`user:me hasaccepted:no answers:1..`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame%20hasaccepted%3Ano%20answers%3A1..)

The the [search help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) in the help center for other goodies.

Comment: It's even better to add `answers:1..` as open questions without answers are not relevant, too.

Comment: "is:question" is redundant here, since only questions can satisfy "hasaccepted:*". http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/221568

Comment: @3524344: thanks, makes a lot of sense too. Edited.